# Writing hyperlinks into XlsxWriter tables

Tags: xlsxwriter

I'm working on a script that gets its data from the [Jira REST API](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/rest-apis/) and presents relevant details to the user as a table in an Excel file generated by [XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/index.html). Ideally, I would like the first column to display a hyperlink that leads the user back to the page in Jira where the information originated. Preferably, I would do that by creating hyperlinks that use just the issue key as the link text (rather than the whole URL).

The [Working with Worksheet Tables](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_tables.html) documentation provides the following example of how to pass data into tables:

```
data = [
    ['Apples', 10000, 5000, 8000, 6000],
    ['Pears',   2000, 3000, 4000, 5000],
    ['Bananas', 6000, 6000, 6500, 6000],
    ['Oranges',  500,  300,  200,  700],

]

worksheet.add_table('B3:F7', {'data': data})
```

The `write_url()` method documentation also provides these examples:

```
worksheet.write_url(0, 0, 'https://www.python.org/')
worksheet.write_url('A2', 'https://www.python.org/')
```

What I would like to do, though, is provide the hyperlink details as part of the `data` list. In the example above, I'm envisioning the hyperlink details taking the place of the `Apples`, `Pears`, `Bananas` and `Oranges` strings (such that each might have link text like 'KEY-1' associated with a URL like 'https://jiraserver/browse/KEY-1' and so on). Is there a convenient way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, rather than relying on XlsxWriter for this purpose, I see that the HYPERLINK function in Excel will provide the desired effect.

I simply need to provide something like the following at the desired position in the list.

`issue_hyperlink = f'=HYPERLINK("{issue_url}", "{issue_key}")'`

This will work for what I have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```py
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('table_with_links.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()


# Some sample data for the table.
data = [
    ['KEY-1', 10000, 5000, 8000, 6000],
    ['KEY-2', 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000],
    ['KEY-3', 6000, 6000, 6500, 6000],
    ['KEY-4', 500, 300, 200, 700],

]

# Set the columns widths.
worksheet.set_column('A:E', 10)

# Add a table to the worksheet.
worksheet.add_table('A1:E5')

# Write the data to the table.
for row_num, row_data in enumerate(data):
    for col_num, col_data in enumerate(row_data):
        if col_num == 0:
            worksheet.write_url(row_num + 1, col_num,
                                f'https://jiraserver/browse/{col_data}',
                                None, col_data)
        else:
            worksheet.write(row_num + 1, col_num, col_data)

workbook.close()
```

**Output**:

[image]

I prefer using the real hyperlink instead of the `HYPERLINK` formula because I think it looks less confusing to the end user.